# How to type exponents in Latexian

Tags: superscripts

I'm trying to type X to the power Y as X^{Y} in Latexian but it does not work. Latexian does not seem to understand the SHIFT + 6 Stroke. Are there any other key combination that will produce the result I want on mac?

Comment: Does doing Shift-6 twice produce it? (possibly two of them)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old post but I finally found how to insert this without copy pasting from somewhere else..

`Option+I` then `space`